# GetPrivateProfileString function for MFC application in Win CE

Tags: windows, mfc, windows-ce

I understand that WinCE does not support the above function. However as it has been used in the code I am trying to port to Win CE environment, I am trying to rewrite the function to work in Win CE.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/GetPrivateProfileString.aspx
The code at this link does not work as fstream is not supported. Please let me know how I can modify the above code/ rewrite the code for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you are porting to CE, then just move the config data to the registry. In which case, GetPrivateProfileString would become [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891462.aspx)